# How to check if the newly mined block contains a contract deployment using infura sdk?

Tags: contract-deployment, infura, internal-transactions

I am trying to implement following scenario.

- Get a notification every time a new block is mined.
- Loop through/filter all the transactions in the newly created block.
- Check if the any transaction contains a newly deployed erc20 or
  erc721 token.

I am using infura`s websocket, but I am not sure how to identify if the transaction was new contract deployment.

Answer (score 0):

- You can identify contract deployed by an External Owned Account by looking at the recipient which should be empty.

  There's no reliable way to identify a contract as ERC20. You can query the created address for known [ERC20 functions](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) like `name()`, `symbol()`, `totalSupply()`, `balanceOf()`, etc.

  Fortunately for [ERC721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) compliant tokens it should be easier since they must support [EIP165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165).
- A contract can deploy a token through an internal transaction. Unfortunately there's no easy access to internal transactions, you need a client to implement that functionality.